# MvvmCross - instantiate ViewModel with activity (context) parameter

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvm, mvvmcross

Using MvvmCross, I have created a cross-platform method to translate strings on Android and iOS so I can use one shared `translate()` method in my `ViewModel`. I have a shared interface `ILocalizationHelper` in my core project and in each platform I created a `LocalizationHelper` class that inherits from the interface. So my `ViewModel` now contains an `ILocalizationHelper` instance on which I can use my `translate()` method.

**The problem:** to translate strings on Android using `GetString()`, I need a Context (Activity). So instantiating this `LocalizationHelper` isn't straightforward. Currently I solve this using a `Translator` property in my `MvxViewModel` that I can set from my view.

My `Fragment` class is as follows:

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(AccountViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, AddToBackStack = true)]
[Register("appname.Android.Fragments.Account.LoginFragment")]
public class LoginFragment : MvxFragment<LoginViewModel>
{
    base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentLogin, container, false);

    ViewModel.Translator = new LocalizationHelper(Activity);
}
```

Now I was thinking that this might be bad practice (is it?). So I'd prefer to inject my LocalizationHelper instance using the ViewModel's constructor. But I don't see how I can do that, if it's even possible at all:

```
private ILocalizationHelper _translator;

public ILocalizationHelper Translator
{
    get { return _translator; }
    set { _translator = value; }
}    

public LoginViewModel(ILocalizationHelper localizationHelper)
{
    _translator = localizationHelper;
}
```

Thanks for any enlightenment on the best practice concerning this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Context` should be set when you initialize `LocalizationHelper`. I'm assuming this can be treated as a singleton, so the best place to do that is from the `Setup` class in your Android project.

Override `InitializeFirstChance()` and register the singleton with Mvx IoC. Then you'll be able to use constructor injection in your ViewModel.

Since the context is already captured by the singleton, your ViewModel will not have to worry about it. This is pretty much how Plugins work (albeit Mvx has auto-registration of plugins).

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    private readonly Context _applicationContext;

    public Setup(Context applicationContext) : base(applicationContext)
    {
        // save copy of application context
        _applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
    {
        base.InitializeFirstChance();

        // instantiate and register helper
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ILocalizationHelper>(new LocalizationHelper(_applicationContext));
    }
}


public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly ILocalizationHelper _localizationHelper;

    // constructor injector of helper singleton
    public MyViewModel(ILocalizationHelper localizationHelper)
    {
        _localizationHelper = localizationHelper;

        // you will now be able to use _localizationHelper from the rest of the ViewModel
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I understand how it works now :)

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of `IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity` which is registered against the current top `Activity` to get an activity context inside of your android `LocalizationHelper` implementation.

`var context = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;`

Comment: Thanks, I found out about IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity but didn't know where it could be used. VS also didn't let me import it before now because I used it in the wrong method/class. Your solution also solved my problem, but because I think of my class as something global I prefer to use the application context method. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could register the `ApplicationContext` in the DependencyContainer and inject it into your `LocalizationHelper` implementation.

If you had to use the current activity context you could register it as a `Func<Context>` (and resolve it on every call to `Translate`) or just do what @Plac3Hold3r suggested and inject the IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity into your `LocalizationHelper` implementation.

Comment: By "register in the DependencyContainer", you probably mean Mvx.Register...() right, like @Kiliman 's answer? Or is there another way? Thanks for helping!